# Java inventory programming

Tags: java

```
C:\Users\gator\Documents\InventoryPart1.java:101: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Television(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,double)
location: class Television
        Television sony = new Television ("SONY368", "Sony Vega", 2, 899.99);
                          ^
```

1 error
 This is the error I get when i try to compile my java code below: I need to know what to change in order for it to compile can anyone help? I don't understand the int in the error message.

```
//Author:           Walter Rutherford
//Date:             Feb. 03/2011
//Class:            IT/215 week five inventory program 1

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Television {

    private String itemNumber;
    private String productName;
    private double units;
    private double unitPrice;
    private double unitsTotal;
    //constructor
    public Television (String itemNumber, String productName, double units, double unitprice, double unitsTotal) {
        setItemNumber(itemNumber);
        setProductName(productName);
        setUnits(units);
        setUnitPrice(unitPrice);
        unitsTotal = units ++;
    }

    //accessor methods for class variables
    public String getItemNumber () {
        return itemNumber;
    }

    public void setItemNumber (String itemNumber) {
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
    }

    public String getProductName () {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName (String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public double getUnits () {
        return units;
    }

    public void setUnits (double units) {
        this.units = units;
    }

    public double getUnitPrice () {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice (double unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice = units * unitPrice;
    }

    public double getUnitsTotal () {
        return unitsTotal;
    }

    public void setUnitsTotal (double unitsTotal) {
        this.unitsTotal = units ++;
    }


}

public class InventoryPart1 {

    public static void main (String args[]) {


        int units;

        double unitPrice;

        double unitsTotal;
        unitsTotal = units ++;

        double unitsPrice;
        unitsPrice = units * unitPrice;

        double unitsTotalPrice;
        unitsTotalPrice = unitsTotal * unitPrice;

        double totalInventory;
        totalInventory = unitsTotal * unitsTotalPrice;


        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat. getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

        //create an instance of the Television class
        Television sony = new Television ("SONY368", "Sony Vega", 2, 899.99);

        //use the methods from class Television to output the inventory details.
        System.out.println("Item Number: " + sony.getItemNumber());

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + sony.getProductName());

        System.out.print("Number of Units: ");
        System.out.println(nf.format(units));

        System.out.print("Unit Price: ");
        System.out.println(nf.format(unitPrice));

        System.out.print("Units Total: ");
        System.out.println(nf.format(unitsTotal));

        System.out.print("Units Total Price: ");
        System.out.println(nf.format(unitsTotalPrice));

        System.out.print("Total Inventory: ");
        System.out.println(nf.format(totalInventory));
    }

}
```

Comment: If this is a homework, it should have a `homework` tag, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor takes 5 parameters, and you try to call it with only 4. Should Java try to invent a value for the missing one?

Answer (score 0):

```
symbol  : constructor Television(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,double)
location: class Television
        Television sony = new Television ("SONY368", "Sony Vega", 2, 899.99);
                      ^
```

> I don't understand the int in the error message.

The message is trying to tell you that it can't find a constructor that matches the arguments you provided when you invoked the constructor here:

```
Television sony = new Television ("SONY368", "Sony Vega", 2, 899.99);
```

Specifically, its saying that based on how you invoked this constructor, it needs to look for a constructor that looks like this:

```
constructor Television(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,double)
```

Notice the method parameters it says your call requires.  Howeve, the constructor in your `Television` class is this:

```
public Television (String ..., String ..., double ..., double ..., double ...)
```

I elided out the parameter names to make it clearer.  See the difference between what parameters the compiler says your call of the constructor needed versus what your constructor really requires?  In particular, notice that you invoked the constructor with 4 arguments and the constructor you wrote in the class has 5 parameters.

Thus the compiler looked in the class for other constructors with 4 parameters that were type-compatible with the arguments you provided and it could not find one. Since it couldn't find one, the compiler said:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Television(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,double)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am new at this and this class is really hard.